# Google AdSense scorecard : Text and image ads enabled is marked as Yellow

Tags: google-adsense

Start with definitions:

**Yellow:** Satisfactory. You could make some further improvements to this item.

I have few sites using Google AdSense to make cents (yes, cents only). On recent update of Google AdSense, a new module called Scorecard displayed on my dashboard.

In item **Revenue optimization > Text and image ads enabled** , it is marked as Yellow. But I have already enabled Text and Image ads in all my sites. Why does it still having Yellow instead of Green? Is it a bug of Google AdSense Scorecard ?

Comment: I've enabled all my idle/hidden/active ads to both AND ensured my global settings allow both, but I'm still getting this report. Is this a glitch? Or am I missing something? Would be great if Google could provide a bit more clarity around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "text and image ads" can be set at two levels: for your entire account, or for a single ad unit.

Maybe you've set them different on these ads units, which would override the account-wide setting.

The scorecard does show green on my account, so it's not a system-wide bug.

Comment: Thanks Rob - I didn't know about the global setting and I was having the same issue. However my global setting was 'Text and image ads' and all the ads in the list were 'Text and image ads' as well. But I did have some hidden/idle ads and they were 'Text ads only' - so I changed these as well even though I am not using these ads anymore.